# Project deployment via Denojs, deployctl command line

Tags: javascript, node.js, deno

after deployment project through command line deployctl(Denojs), in logs write "required --unstable". How write this flag in command deploy? In local test I write --unstable and work.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? (The version of `deno`, `deployctl`, the commands used, the complete contents of a deployment without any non-public external dependencies, etc.). It's hard to debug without reproduction information.

Comment: This is not possible. Only stable APIs are supported on Deno Deploy. See https://deno.com/deploy/docs/runtime-api#deno-apis.